# Django user is SimpleLazyObject in Sentry

Tags: django, sentry

Trying to send the logged on username to Sentry.  If hard coded in settings, I get the expected result on the Sentry dashboard.  However I can't set  the username in settings.

```
#settings.py
from sentry_sdk import configure_scope
    with configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.user = {"username": "Joe Soap"}
```

So I am not sure where I should be doing this:

```
    with configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.user = {"username": request.user.username}
```

I have tried my landing view and login view. But just get my IP Address back on the sentry dashboard.

```
#views.py
@login_required
def landing(request):
    context={}

    with configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.user = {"username": request.user.username}


    return render(request,'paysched/landing.html',context)
```

Python and Django are not my home language, so my questions really are 
A) can I do this? 
B) and if so, where/how.

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Comment: If you initialize the SDK with `send_default_pii=True`, you should see user data in Sentry without extra code. However, what you're doing here should be fine, and I don't really understand why it doesn't work for you

Comment: Thank you, @Markus, that does return a user ID, which is a start and better than an ip address.  With over 200 users I would like an email address or username though.

Comment: Could it be possible that your user object just has no username, or that the attribute is an empty string or `None`?

Comment: Also please check the output when running with `debug=True`, this would show you any errors that might happen when trying to access that attribute.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding Sentry interface. I have just go my first real Sentry error from our Live deployment, the user tag is the IP address, but digging into the error I came across this: `username <SimpleLazyObject: <User: Tracy>> `
The live release has my landing page changes, but not your default_pii in init. So things are working. 

I did check the user object exists and ran debug = true in QA, no issues there.

Comment: The fact that we print out `SimpleLazyObject` in the UI seems like a bug. Could you file a bug report at https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated Sentry SDK 0.10.2, has resolved this problem.