# Send additional user context in Flask to Sentry

Tags: python, flask, sentry

Similar to [this question on setting user context in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672021/sending-the-logged-on-username-to-sentry-in-django), I'm having difficulty setting user context for Sentry logging in Flask. I'm using `sentry-sdk[flask]==0.10.2`.

In my `dashboard` view once the user is logged in, I call `configure_scope()` to build out the user scope:

```python
from sentry_sdk import configure_scope

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    user = current_user

    # user = {
    #     'name': 'Some Name',
    #     'custom_id': 12345
    #  }

    with configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.user = {
            "id": user.custom_id,
            "username": user.name,
        }
```

Logging `scope` shows an object in memory: `<Scope id=0x107d37318 name=flask>`

Sending this to Sentry with a route that calls the `division_by_zero` error triggers an Issue but it only includes the user ID (which is correct) and the user's IP address...none of the custom information in the user scope is included, even if I hardcode a value.

In the Sentry dashboard, I only see the user database ID (which is correct) and IP address:

[image: Sentry error details]
[image: Sentry user block]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot where you expect the data to be?

Comment: Just added screenshots. It's totally possible that I'm looking in the wrong places.

Comment: @Brian On the sentry github page they say that you can use Flask-User to add additional data. https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/fed714ae722242cabdf6c45d2db061acc9e79f0d/sentry_sdk/integrations/flask.py#L197 line #227

Comment: Could it be because I'm redefining `user`?

Comment: Sorry, there are no screenshots to me in your post. Your code should be fine, it will be merged with the data from Flask-User.

Comment: yeah @Brian scroll down a bit more, there we should show all attributes of the user. it's just that they're not available as tags, if you want those you need to explicitly set them

Comment: That's where I was looking - in the user section. All I see is ID and IP address.